# Constant Crash to desktop with any UE4 Application

Tags: technical-issues

Title. I've noticed that every single game that I own that runs off of the Unreal 4 engine crashes to desktop randomly and it's driven mad for months. The culprit has been this DLL file: **nvwgf2umx.dll**

I have searched and looked for hours at a time. I've booted up into safe mode and cleaned my Nvidia drivers, went to several different older versions and to no avail these applications still crash. I've removed overlays because I know overlays injecting into the application can get funky. here is the latest event viewer log.

- Faulting application name: Mordhau-Win64-Shipping.exe, version: 4.20.3.0, time stamp: 0x5d10e73f
- Faulting module name: nvwgf2umx.dll, version: 26.21.14.3160, time stamp: 0x5d2f8c22
- Exception code: 0xc0000005
- Fault offset: 0x0000000000f4a209
- Faulting process id: 0x4264
- Faulting application start time: 0x01d5441b698a3c9f
- Faulting application path: `Z:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Mordhau\Mordhau\Binaries\Win64\Mordhau-Win64-Shipping.exe`
- Faulting module path: `C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_dispi.inf_amd64_547eeefb57db4499\nvwgf2umx.dll`
- Report Id: e9c0b53e-3274-497c-80f4-daa4a8702ae3
- Faulting package full name:
- Faulting package-relative application ID:

My Computer specs:

> - Processor    Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700K CPU @ 4.00GHz, 4001 Mhz,
> - Installed Physical Memory (RAM)  32.0 GB
> - ASUS ROG Strix GeForce® GTX 1070

Can someone advise me with anything?